# Integer to byte casting in Java

Tags: java

In Java we can do

```
byte b = 5;
```

But why can't we pass same argument to a function which accepts `byte`

```
myObject.testByte(5);
public void testByte (byte b)
{
  System.out.println("Its byte");
}
```

It gives following error

```
The method testByte(byte) in the type Apple is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

PS: May be a silly question, I think I need to revise my basics again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hard-coded initializer values are somewhat special in Java - they're assumed to have a coercion to the type of the variable you're initializing. Essentially, that first bit of code effectively looks like this:

```
byte b = (byte) 5;
```

If you did this...

```
myObject.testByte((byte) 5);
```

...you wouldn't get that error, but if you don't do that, then the `5` is created by default as an `int`, and not automatically coerced.

Comment: Sounds convincing. Is there any special reason for it ?

Comment: Mostly convenience - the spec designers didn't want to have to create different format for byte literals versus numeric literals for initializing things, and since the type of the variable is part of the declaration, it's very obvious what kind of box you're putting it into - `byte b = 5` makes it very clear that `5` is going to be put into a `byte`. Function calls, on the other hand, are not nearly as clear - for instance, what if your method was just named `testFoo`? `testFoo(5)` doesn't look any different really from `testFoo(1024)`, but the latter wouldn't *actually* work properly.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that when you are *narrowing* a primitive, you must explicitly make a cast - so you acknowledge a possible loss of data.

To illustrate, when casting `5` there is no loss because the value is within the `-128...127` byte value range, but consider a larger `int` value, say `300` - if you cast to byte, you must throw away some bits to make it fit into 8 bits.

The topic is covered in full [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Why implicit casting is done while initializing value and not in function call ? `5` is also within the range and there will not be any loss of bit.

Comment: The compiler will throw an error if the (constant) value is too large for the target type. However, this compiles: `byte b = (byte)1000;`

Answer (score 4):

Normally, converting an `int` to a `byte` without an explicit cast is not allowed.

However, if the conversion is part of an assignment, and the value is a statically-known constant that will fit in the destination type, the compiler will perform the conversion automatically.

This special behaviour is described in [section 5.2 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190806). It is a special case that only applies to assignment; it does not apply to conversions in other contexts.

---

Now that I think about it, the lack of auto-narrowing for arguments is probably to avoid issues with overload resolution. If I have methods `#foo(short)` and `#foo(char)`, it's not clear which one `foo(65)` should call. You could have special rules to get around this, but it's easier to just require the caller to be explicit in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for the information. `5` is also a known constant so why compiler donot cast it to `byte` in case of function call ?

Comment: The special rule that automatically narrows constants is only applied to *assignment conversions*, for some reason that is not explained in the JLS. I have updated my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: That is a very good question, Ajinkya.  The JLS seems to indicate the assignment conversion is applied only in an assignment expression (via its link to Chapter 15), yet it does perform the conversion during initialization but not when passing an argument, _even though it is by value_.  It seems to me the language could have been designed to apply assignment conversion in this case, so either they chose not to for simplicity sake, OR there really is some semantic problem with doing so.  This would be good to know.

Comment: @Ray: Yes.Its becomes really easy when you why it is that way.

Comment: @Stuart good insight on overload resolution.  (I had already +1'd before that, but good addition anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

You must cast your argument `5` to type `byte` in your method `testByte`.  Java looks specifically at the argument type.

Change it to:

```
myObject.testByte( (byte) 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer literals are by default `int` in Java. And in `myObject.testByte(5);` `5` is an integer literal which will be treated as `int`.

As all you know Java is strictly types language, so it will not allow to assign an `int` to a `byte`. All you need to have explicit type-casting.