# Setting byte field in an object

Tags: java

I have a simple program as below:

```
class SerializationBox implements Serializable
{

    private byte    serializableProp    = 10;

    public byte getSerializableProp()
    {
        return serializableProp;
    }

    public void setSerializableProp(byte serializableProp)
    {
        serializableProp = serializableProp;
    }
}

public class SerializationSample
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        SerializationBox serialB = new SerializationBox();
        serialB.setSerializableProp(1); // Here i get an error
}
}
```

At the indicated place in code I get error that "The method setSerializableProp(byte) in the type SerializationBox is not applicable for the arguments (int)".

I believed that as per the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html , I am allowed to pass -128 to 127 as the arguement.

Please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you specify a byte literal in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193883/how-do-you-specify-a-byte-literal-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer to byte casting in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369493/integer-to-byte-casting-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **cast** the integer to `byte`:

```
serialB.setSerializableProp((byte) 1);
```

**Notes:**

- When you do

  ```
  private byte serializableProp = 10;
  ```
- `10` is a integer, not a binary number. To specify that the number is a binary you have to use the following syntax:

  ```
  private byte serializableProp = 0b10;
                                  ^^
  ```

Comment: One hint... private byte serializableProp = 0b10; will work only in java 1.7 or later as suggested by compiler error Binary literals can only be used with source level 1.7 or greater"

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to call `setSerializableProp()` method with a integer literal.That is giving you compilation error.
So down cast the integer literal to byte like below.
`setSerializableProp((byte)1)`

Answer (score 0):

`serialB.setSerializableProp((byte)1);`

This will explicitly cast your integer literal (`1`) into a `byte`